# Match and Merge in XSLT 1.0 for multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

The XSLT below works fine and remove duplicate node when we have single node 'pos' but doesn't work when we have multiple 'pos' node.

Data inside the node 'pos' has to be independently processed to remove duplicate with respect to data of other 'pos' node. Data inside node 'pos' is independent of each other. 
When using the below XSLT, it is merging data for both 'pos' node with removing duplicate. 
Any input will be of great help

Sample message is

```
<document>
    <party>
        <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE1</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE2</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE3</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE4</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>                    
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE5</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE6</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE7</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE8</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE1</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE1</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE2</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE3</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE4</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>                    
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE5</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE6</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE7</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE8</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>
    </party>
</document>
```

The XSLT which I am using here is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:key name="group" match="attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureInformation']/row"
        use="concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature'])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureInformation']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature']))[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureStats']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | key('group', concat(../attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', ../attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature']))/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureStats']/row"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
    <party>
        <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE1</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE2</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE3</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE4</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE5</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE6</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE7</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE8</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORAGE1</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE1</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE2</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE3</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE4</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE5</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE6</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrGroupMany name="temperatureStats">
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE7</attr>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <attr name="StatsCode">CODE8</attr>
                        </row>
                    </attrGroupMany>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>


    </party>
</document>
```

Any input will be very valuable as this solution is an imp part of a bigger problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below XSLT works to remove duplicate within nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">



<xsl:key name="group" match="party/pos/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureInformation']/row"
    use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::pos), '|', attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature'])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pos/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureInformation']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(ancestor::pos), '|', attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature']))[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pos/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureInformation']/row/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureStats']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | key('group', concat(generate-id(ancestor::pos), '|',../attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '|', ../attrQualMany[@name = 'temperature']))/attrGroupMany[@name = 'temperatureStats']/row"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```